# getprotobyname of a host

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have run into a small dead end in my project. I need to retrieve the supported protocols of any given device (with linux kernel) within  the network. I know that `getprotobyname` method does the job but with my current knowledge I have only been successful in implementing it to get the protocol details of the local machine in which the code is running. The code is as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

        int i;
    struct protoent *proto = getprotobyname("ipv6");
    if ( proto != NULL )
    {
        printf("Official name: %s\n", proto->p_name);
        printf("Port#: %d\n", proto->p_proto);
        for ( i = 0; proto->p_aliases[i] != 0; i++ )
        .
    printf("Alias[%d]: %s\n", i+1,
            proto->p_aliases[i]);
    }
    else
        perror("protocol not found");
}
```

My query is how can I implement this solution where I could parse the IP address of the target device so that the `getprotobyname` could try to identify the target devices protocols. Any sample code segment or reference is much appreciated. Solving this would take a great weight off my shoulders and thanks again :)

**EDIT**

Any alternative methods to to perform my requirement would also be very much helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: you can't.

`getprotocolbyname()` just retrieves static information from a local (/etc/protocols) text file (protocol names, ip header protocol ident number, ...) and is meant to map numbers to human readable protocol information.

The fact that any protocol appears within that file doesn't mean at all its supported by the local machine. This is very similar to e.g. /etc/services which matches port numbers to service names. If a service appears within the file, this doesn't mean the machine offers this service.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up sir.. is there any way that I could accomplish my requirement?

Comment: There's no registry, unfortunately, like there is with RPC. The only way you could _try_ to get the information you need would be to scan every port, but (a) that's slow, (b) that's a horrible thing to do to someone else's machine, and (c) just because you connected to the right port doesn't mean it responds to the right protocol. As an example of the extreme, BitTorrent uses "tracker" servers to help people find each other, basically public registries.